# Getting field label with entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

Say I am iterating through a list of field names, and I have loaded a particular node using entity_metadata_wrapper().

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
```

Shouldn't I be able to just grab the label by using the following command?

Or is this not the correct command to do what I want?

```
        foreach($field_names as $item)
        {
           $label = $wrapper->$item->label();
        }
```

Here's the field as it is in the actual node:

```
'field_grade_comment' => 
    array (size=13)
      'default_value' => null
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'display' => 
        array (size=4)
          'default' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          'email' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          'teaser' => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
          'node_reference_embedded_view' => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
      'label' => string 'Grade Comment' (length=13)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$fields = $wrapper->getPropertyInfo();

foreach($fields as $field => $info) {
  $label = $info['label'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$entity_type = 'node';

$bundle_name = 'article';

$field_name = 'field_some_field';

$info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);

$label = $info['label'];
```